# Обработка принимаемых данных в php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Есть `AJAX` запрос:

```
function getCourierInfo(courierId) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:'http://domain.com/AppClient_1.0_domain/admin/courierchange.php?courier_id='+courierId,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            complete: function (courierDetails) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://mydomain.com.ua/wp-content/themes/mytheme/Controllers/CourierController.php",
                    data: courierDetails
                })
            }
        })
    }
```

Делаю запрос на сервер приложения, и потом результаты этого запроса хочу отправить на обработку на сервере административной панели(моего сайта, проще говоря).
Как мне эти данные принять, обработать и вернуть ответ?

Comment: У вас два ajax. В первом же у вас не возникает проблем с принятием данных. Почему вы думаете, что во втором что-то делается по другому?

Comment: В первом случае я получаю данные на страницу, с которой отправляю запрос,как они формируются на сервере,с которого я получаю данные - мне неизвестно, а во втором случае мне нужно отправить данные в свой контроллер и обработать их. Вопрос именно в том, как эти данные принять, и как сформировать ответ.

Comment: Перед вторым `jQuery.ajax({` сделайте `console.log(courierDetails);` и в консоли браузера смотрите структуру данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, начнем с того, что courierDetails у вас будет собственно весь вывод страницы, т.е. строка. Вы нигде эту переменную не обрабатываете, не парсите из неё значения, вообще никак с ней не работаете, а сразу запихиваете во второй запрос в data. Но в data должен передаваться именно массив значений навроде

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://mydomain.com/muscript.php",
    data: {
        value1: '1',
        value2: '2',
        value3: '3'
    }
})
```

А вот уже после того, как приведете данные к этому виду, можете их отправлять. И тогда так как у вас передается методом POST - то значение которые переданы вы можете в скрипте получать из массива `$_POST` - в данном примере переменные будут доступны как `$_POST['value1']`, `$_POST['value2']`, `$_POST['value3']` (или же из массива `$_REQUEST` - это объединение массивов `$_GET` и `$_POST`)

Comment: А просто отправить данные которые я получил из первого запроса нельзя? Не распарсивая массив полученных данных на странице, с которой я отправляю запросы, а распарсить их уже в `CourierController.php`

Comment: Можно. Просто нужно тогда отправлять `data: {input: courierDetails}`, а уже в php работать с `$_POST['input']` Хотя, чисто из опыта - могу сказать, что правильнее формировать вывод из php файла в JSON строку - тогда в JS достаточно использовать `JSON.parse(string)` если нужно будет что-то сделать с данными, а отправить в php можно будет с помощью `JSON.stringify(object)` или просто строкой, а в php использовать `json_decode(string, true)`. В общем, я за то, чтоб данные всегда передавались в каком-то стандартизированном формате - вам же самому проще будет в будущем.